# Using System.Windows.Forms.Timer.Start()/Stop() versus Enabled = true/false

Tags: c#, .net, timer

Suppose we are using System.Windows.Forms.Timer in a .Net application, **Is there any meaningful difference between using the Start() and Stop() methods on the timer, versus using the Enabled property?**

For example, if we wish to pause a timer while we do some processing, we could do:

```
myTimer.Stop();
// Do something interesting here.
myTimer.Start();
```

or, we could do:

```
myTimer.Enabled = false;
// Do something interesting here.
myTimer.Enabled = true;
```

If there is no significant difference, **is there a consensus in the community about which option to choose?**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As stated by both [BFree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012948/using-system-windows-forms-timer-start-stop-versus-enabled-true-false/1012981#1012981) and [James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012948/using-system-windows-forms-timer-start-stop-versus-enabled-true-false/1012979#1012979), there is no difference in [`Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.start(VS.71).aspx)`\`[`Stop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop(VS.71).aspx) versus [`Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.enabled(VS.71).aspx) with regards to functionality. However, the decision on which to use should be based on context and your own coding style guidelines. It depends on how you want a reader of your code to interpret what you've written.

For example, if you want them to see what you're doing as starting an operation and stopping that operation, you probably want to use `Start/Stop`. However, if you want to give the impression that you are enabling the accessibility or functionality of a feature then using `Enabled` and `true/false` is a more natural fit.

I don't think a consensus is required on just using one or the other, you really have to decide based on the needs of your code and its maintenance.

Comment: ok so basically when the initial value of the Timer.Enabled is "false", and in run time, I called Start(), the Timer.Enabled value now would "true" right? sorry I should write a simple code instead.

Answer (score 15):

From Microsoft's Documentation:

> Calling the Start method is the same
>   as setting Enabled to true. Likewise,
>   calling the Stop method is the same as
>   setting Enabled to false.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.enabled.aspx

So, I guess there's no difference...

Answer (score 6):

No they are eachothers equivalent.

See [Timer.Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.enabled(VS.71).aspx) and [Timer.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.start(VS.71).aspx) / [Timer.Stop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop(VS.71).aspx)

To add to your Question about the consensus, I would say its probably better practice to use the Start/Stop methods and its also better for readability I suppose.

James.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I don't like setting properties to have too much consequence other than changing a value, so I tend to stick to the `Start()`/`Stop()` as it's clear(er) to me that when you are invoking a method, you are asking for something to happen.

That said, I don't suppose there is a whole lot of ambiguity about what setting `Enabled = true` is going to do :)

Comment: I'm not sure about that... until I read the documentation, my mental model was that Start()/Stop() caused the timer to start or stop counting, whereas setting Enabled would govern whether or not events fired when the timer elapsed (this would be useful in cases where you might need to temporarily prevent events, but keep the same schedule for them if you reenabled them later).

Comment: @Jules That's understandable, but wrong :) If you set `Enabled = true` the next event will fire after `Interval`, not whenever the next one would have fired if you hadn't disabled them.

Comment: Yes; my point is that this is a plausible interpretation, so you should avoid the ambiguity by not using the Enabled property, rather than suggesting it's actually true. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple code to test how `Enabled`, `Start()`, `Stop()` work with each other.

Make a test Windows form app, add two simple buttons and paste this code inside `Form1()` constructor:

```
int c = 0;
Timer tmr1 = new Timer()
{
    Interval = 100,
    Enabled= false
};
tmr1.Tick += delegate
{
    c++;
};

// used to continously monitor the values of "c" and tmr1.Enabled
Timer tmr2 = new Timer()
{
    Interval = 100,
    Enabled = true
};
tmr2.Tick += delegate
{
    this.Text = string.Format("c={0}, tmr1.Enabled={1}", c, tmr1.Enabled.ToString());
};

button1.Click += delegate
{
    tmr1.Start();
};
button2.Click += delegate
{
    tmr1.Stop();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `timer.Stop()` and `timer.Start()`, because they are subs of `timer.Enabled`. If you want to set the timer to false at the beginning of the application (at loading) , you must used `timer.Enabled = false`, `timer.Stop()` won't work. This is why I use `timer.Enabled = false/true`.