# C# show timer in textbox

Tags: c#, timer, textbox

I'm trying to make a timer run in a textbox and I haven't had any luck.

This is the code I'm using:

```
private static System.Timers.Timer timer;
...
private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    timer.Enabled = true;
}
...
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    TimeTb.Text = e.SignalTime.ToString();
}
```

But nothing happens.

I tried this:

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.SignalTime.ToString(), 
    "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
}
```

And it worked fine. Anyone know why it isn't working with my textbox?

Comment: You must have another long running process that's actually running on the UI thread. This code would work.

Comment: Which  one you used windows or web application ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran, for a `MessageBox` to work it would have to be a Windows application.

Comment: I use window application

Comment: Assuming you're in **WinForms**, have you tried with `TimeTb.Update();`?

Comment: TimeTb.Update did nothing =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Elapsed Event runs on a different Thread then the UI. Its not allowed to manipulate UI Objects from a different thread and an Exception should surface in your EventHandler. Since you don't handle Exceptions there you won't notice it.

In `StartBtn_Click` set the `SynchronizingObject` Property of the Timer to this (the form). Then the elapsed Event will be synchronized with the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should start the timer first.

Take a look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.start.aspx

So add:

```
timer.Start();
```

Comment: I thought `timer.Enabled = true;` did that :O

Comment: @Litari, no, `Start` must be called.

Comment: @Litari if you were never calling start how could "it worked fine" be the case?

Comment: There might be an exception being thrown if the Timer is running on a different thread. Have you tried using the Windows.Forms.Timer class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

Comment: @Secret Squirrel: In the link: "You can also start timing by setting Enabled to true."

Comment: As in the documentation page, it says ***You can also start timing by setting Enabled to true.***

Comment: Setting enabled to true will start the timer.

Comment: @Litari Thanks now I have learnt something :D, although I did suspect as my question stated how could it have worked before without using `start` method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012948/using-system-windows-forms-timer-start-stop-versus-enabled-true-false

Answer (score 1):

Put a `try catch` around `OnTimedEvent` and see if there are any issues with threading.
If there are, try using the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` which can resolve the issues of cross threading.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

As stated:

> Implements a timer that raises an event at user-defined intervals.
>   This timer is optimized for use in Windows Forms applications and must
>   be used in a window.

Answer (score 1):

Your OnTimedEvent callback will not be called on the UI thread, so you will get an exception in there trying to set the textbox text.  So you need to change the event handler to look like this:

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  if (TimeTb.InvokeRequired)
  {
    TimeTb.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                  OnTimedEvent(source, e);
                });

  }

  TimeTb.Text = e.SignalTime.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this._timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        this._timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
        this._timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_timer_Tick);
        _timer.Start();
    }

void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    t= t.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
    textBox.Text = t.Hours + ":" + t.Minutes + ":" + t.Seconds + ":" + t.Milliseconds;
}
```

Edit :

How to add Assembly: WindowsBase

[image]

Comment: what do I have to include to be able to use DispatcherTimer? `using System.Windows.Threading` doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Use Assembly: WindowsBase

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `Application.DoEvents();` after `TimeTb.Text = e.SignalTime.ToString();` would work, though using it would not be recommended ([Use of Application.DoEvents()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents)).