# Timer to make label appear and disappear is very slow and unresponsive

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I want to make it so that when a form is clicked, a label appears for x milliseconds. then disappears.

By the way I tried replacing `timer1.Enabled=true` with `timer1.Start()` and `timer1.Enabled=false` with `timer1.Stop()` but it makes no difference.

Here is my code.  I have a form, I've programmatically created a label which I've added onto the form and I've programmatically created a timer. Interval set to 300 milliseconds(I might make it less later, but for now, 300 milliseconds).

The idea is that the label starts off with .`Visible=false`, and then when the form is clicked, the label should become visible for 300 milliseconds, then go invisible.  I try to achieve this by saying the first time the timer runs, i.e. after it is enabled, make the label visible, and the second time, make the label invisible.

I manage that even without needing to count how many times the timer runs, I manage it by simply saying that if the label is invisible(that must be the first time the timer has run having just been enabled) then make it visible, and if the label is visible(i.e. it must be the second time the timer has run) then make it invisible and disable the timer.

The problem is it's unresponsive in the sense of being not very responsive and being slow to respond. I click, I have an event for `MouseDown`, but there's a delay between that and the label appearing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication16
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Label label1;
        Timer timer1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.Interval = 300;
            timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;

            label1 = new Label();
            label1.Text = "blah";
            label1.Visible = false;
            this.Controls.Add(label1);            
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (label1.Visible == false) { label1.Visible = true;  } 
            else { label1.Visible = false; timer1.Enabled = false; }

        }

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: turned out a simple reason, i'll post an answer

Comment: also, this confirms no difference between enable and disable, vs start and stop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012948/using-system-windows-forms-timer-start-stop-versus-enabled-true-false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that after the timer is enabled, it doesn't immediately run the tick method. You see this clearly if you make the interval longer like 3000milliseconds.  So given that fact, the solution is thus this.

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Visible = false;
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Visible = true;
        timer1.Enabled = true; //will wait timer1.interval milliseconds then run tick           
    }
```