# Automatically hide the picture in winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am working on windows forms in c#. i want to display a picture when I run the program and then that picture automatically disappear after few seconds.
For this I made a picture box and gave it a background picture.
(I also try giving picture at form load event.)

Then a timer internal property is set to 1000.
I made a global variable:

```
int count=0;
```

in timer tick event I write a code:

```
private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            

            count++;
            if(count==3)
            {
                pictureBox1.Visible = false;
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
```

this code does not work.

I tried on the picture click event

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        }
```

It works but I want to do this automatically not on clicking.
How can I do this?

Comment: Show the part which creates and *starts* timer.

Comment: `timer1_Tick_1` indicates there is *already* `timer1_Tick` event. Check which handler is assigned as timer event in properties (assuming now you are creating timer as form component using designer).

Comment: Btw, you can change timer interval (increase by 3 times) instead of using `count`.

Comment: @Sinatr I used timer from toolbox and double click on that to have its code where is write my coding given in question

Comment: Set breakpoint on `count++` line. If it doesn't hit during runtime your timer is either not enabled (means it doesn't start) or you did a mess with handlers. Check timer properties in designer.

Comment: Make sure your timer object is enabled, by default, it is not.

Comment: @LittleStar, out of curiocity could you tell us what was wrong? It may help future readers (assuming you won't delete question). Consider to [post self-answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250204/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr in the properties of timer, enable was false so i make it 'true' then it was working fine

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your code

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

Comment: If timer is added as form component, then it's more convenient to enable timer by setting properties of component in one place - using designer. `Enabled = true` [is same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1012948/1997232) as `Start()`.